# Is it better to cache BinaryFormatter or keep re-creating it?

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

Is the code below good practice, or is it better to cache BinaryFormatter in a field so it doesn't keep getting re-created?

```
    private void SaveLocalData()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fs = null;

        try
        {
            fs = File.Create(Constants.LOCAL_BINARY_DATA_PATH);
            bf.Serialize(fs, this.localData);
        }
        catch(System.Exception e)
        {
            print("error saving: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's better to delete it. This class isn't just obsolete, insecure and impossible to secure. It's actually disabled in ASP.NET applications starting with .NET 5

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. I was about to use it in production. Looks like I'll have to change the way data is saved.

Answer (score 1):

when you accessing file system make sure you use using statements to avoid any memory leaks

don't see any problem recreating the formatter object

```
    private void SaveLocalData()
    {
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    
        try
        {
            using (var fs = File.Create(Constants.LOCAL_BINARY_DATA_PATH))
            {
                bf.Serialize(fs, this.localData);
            }
                
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            print("error saving: " + e.Message);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about "using" until now. So with "using", I no longer need to call fs.Close()? I noticed you removed the code inside the "finally" block.